# Serving from sessionStorage takes a very long time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

I have a function that is supposed to return a dictionary from sessionStorage if it exists, and if not, it will load the dictionary from the API into sessionStorage and then return the dictionary.

```
self.getDictionary = function(dictionary){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var saved_dictionary = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem('dictionary_' + dictionary));

        if (saved_dictionary && saved_dictionary !== "null"){
            deferred.resolve(saved_dictionary);
        } else {
            var apiData = {module: "Dictionaries", method: "getDictionary", data: {name: dictionary}};
            apiService.execute(apiData).then(function (response) {
                $window.sessionStorage.setItem('dictionary_' + dictionary, JSON.stringify(response));
                deferred.resolve(response);
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

I am trying to cache the dictionary as it is possible extremely large (about 0.5mb JSON).

Sample dictionary:

```
{"DictionaryName":"Gaming","DictionaryCategory":[{"CategoryName":"Games","MandatoryAtLeast":1,"CategoryWords":[{"title":"zelda","score":1,"exact":true,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"mass effect","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false},{"title":"pokemon","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false},{"title":"fallout","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"cs:go","score":1,"exact":true,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"sims","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"until dawn","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"deus ex","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"skyrim","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false}]},{"CategoryName":"Companies","MandatoryAtLeast":1,"CategoryWords":[{"title":"bioware","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false},{"title":"bethesda","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"steam","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false},{"title":"valve","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"alienware","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false}]},{"CategoryName":"other","MandatoryAtLeast":1,"CategoryWords":[{"title":"gamer","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false},{"title":"mods","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"horror","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"survival","score":1,"exact":true,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"multiplayer","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"action","score":1,"exact":true,"mandatory":true,"reject":false},{"title":"fps","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false},{"title":"shooter","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":false,"reject":false},{"title":"mmo","score":1,"exact":false,"mandatory":true,"reject":false}]}]}
```

The problem is that serving the dictionary from the cache is not helping. It takes almost as long to serve the dictionary from sessionStorage as it takes to load it from the remote API.

Why is it taking so long to return from sessionStorage?

Comment: Why do you not check if key is defined in `sessionStorage` before calling `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I guess I could, but I dont think it would make much difference. As far as I know, calling JSON.parse() on a null value is negligble

Comment: how long is long time? What problem does the time taken pose?

Comment: When you store the data, I assume it has to get serialized by the browser in some way. I wouldn't expect it to take that long, but still, my first test would be to try and store a smaller amount of data, and make conclusions/debug further from there.

Comment: Also doesn't appear you store the data in memory once you retrieve it. Once it is parsed, accessing it while stored in service as object will be much much faster

Comment: `JSON.parse(null) !== "null" // true, null !== "null"`

Comment: In order of questions asked:
@charlietfl about 7-8 seconds

Comment: Can  you reproduce issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co, including benchmarks of time differences?

Comment: @SunilD. I guess I can try that

Comment: @charlietfl I do store it - after the apiService.execute.. I have the line:
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('dictionary_' ....

Comment: @guest271314 yes I know that - sometimes the server returns null as answer so it gets saved as a string. I have to check against that and reload if necessary

Comment: @guest271314 unfortunately I can't mnake a plunkr. API is not publicly available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging, it seems like the problem is not the sessionStorage.

The problem is AngularJS taking an age to render the ng-repeat for 1000+ elements. That is the next thing I will have to look into